# Convert date format in last column with awk or other

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have data in a file like this...

```
405,,,405,15.4,0,04/21/12 14:13:29
402,,,402,15.4,0,04/21/12 14:13:37
404,,,404,15.5,0,2012/04/21 14:14:05
404,,,404,15.4,0,2012/04/21 14:14:11
403,,,403,15.4,0,2012/04/21 14:14:17
```

I want to convert the last column to a date in YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss format.

Some of the lines are already in that format so they should be ignored.

I have tried the following awk command but it seems slow, and sometimes throws errors

```
awk -F ',' '{ ("date -d \""$7"\" \"+%Y/%m/%d %T\"") | getline $7; print }' MyFile
```

This doesn't have to be done in awk. I have any utility available at the standard Debian commandline.

Comment: In your date: `04/21/12` == `2012-04-21`. Is it right?

Comment: You're spawning a new process for each line, that's why it is slow.

Comment: Also, AWK is pretty limited if you want to deal with dates correctly, as it lacks a `strptime()`-like functionality.

Comment: Python and Perl have `strptime()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use sed for this rather than awk.  Something like this:

```
sed 's@,\(..\)/\(..\)/\(..\) @,20\3/\1/\2 @'
```

Old answer before question was edited:

You could use `tr : /` to convert colons to slashes, or maybe you can make awk do the replacement directly.  But why you would consider HH/MM/SS a valid format is beyond me.

Comment: Edited question. hh:mm:ss i meant. It is the date format before that that needs shifting around.

Comment: @John Zwinck works nicely, would you care to explain a breakdown of how the sed command moves the date around ??

Comment: @generalexception It finds lines with any two characters (`..`) three times, separated by a front-slash. Each of the two-char pairs is captured and given a number for use in the substitution (`\1`, `\2`, and `\3`). He then puts the third capture first (with a '20' in front of it, the first second and the second third. The bit between the first and second `@` is the "seach" portion and the bit between the second and third `@` is the replace portion. See here for more on sed: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged your question [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), I'll assume you have `gawk` which has some builtin time functions:

```
awk --re-interval -F, '
    $7 !~ /[[:digit:]]{4}\// {
        split($7, a, "[/ :]");
        strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", 
            mktime("20" a[3] " " a[1] " " a[2] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6]))}'
    }
    {
        print
    }'
```